# Are there any examples for programming client/server "Hello world" in C#?

Tags: c#, tcp, client, client-server

I want some fairly simple functionality.

- Server listening for a client
- Clients connecting and sending "Hello server"
- Server acknowledging with "Hello client"

Communication performed using TCP/IP.  I've looked for examples with source code but haven't found anything that I can get working.

Does anyone have any recommended resources?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  MSDN has one here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx

And there's a simpler one here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmeier/archive/2007/10/15/how-to-create-a-hello-world-wcf-service-using-visual-studio.aspx

These use WCF (Windows Communication Foundation), which is probably the simplest way to accomplish what you're describing in your question.

There are other options of course, but WCF is the simplest that I'm aware of.